# Loop through buffer content with different value

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, buffer, bufferedreader

Need help,

I am getting buffer data using plugin and matching iframe tag.

After getting buffer value, I am retrieving iframe src and replacing them with blank src.

When I loop the src values and output and using preg_replace it does not replace value according to loop and replace with the first iframe values...

Here is my code

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'scheck_iframe_value');

function scheck_iframe_value() {

    $get_me_buffers = ob_get_clean();       
    $pattern = '@(.*)(<iframe(?:.*?)</iframe>)(.*)@m';
    ob_start();

    /* if (preg_match($pattern, $get_me_buffers, $get_me_buffers_return)) {  */
    if (preg_match_all($pattern, $get_me_buffers, $get_me_buffers_return, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER)) {            
        $d_new_body_plus = $get_me_buffers_return[0];
        $html = '';
        $sizeofarray = count($d_new_body_plus);         
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($d_new_body_plus); $i++) {
            preg_match('/src="([^"]+)"/', $d_new_body_plus[$i], $match);

            $src = $match[1];
            $content = str_replace($src, '', $d_new_body_plus[$i]);
            $html .= '<div class="wpretarget-iframe-block" style="background-color: lightgray;text-align: center;">'
                    . '<button style="margin: 5px;background-color: blue;color: white;" type="button" class="wpretarget-iframe-content-button-click" data-url=' . $src . ' data-type="iframe">Click to load content of Vimeo</button>'
                    . '<span style="display:none;">' . $content . '</span>'
                    . '</div>';
            $d_new_body_plus = $html;
        }
        echo preg_replace($pattern, $d_new_body_plus, $get_me_buffers);
    } else {
        echo $get_me_buffers;
    }
    ob_flush();
}
```

[image: Screen Shot 1]

[image: Screen Shot 2]

Comment: Try to replace `$d_new_body_plus = $get_me_buffers_return[0];` with `$d_new_body_plus = $get_me_buffers_return;`. If you don't have an error in you main logic your code should work.

Comment: @Petya Thanks for your reply.if i replace with that then how shall i get iframe src to alter.Warning: preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this problem using preg_replace_callback function.And the code are

```
function test_iframe_checker() {   
    $get_me_buffers = ob_get_clean();    
    $pattern = '@(.*)(<iframe(?:.*?)</iframe>)(.*)@m';
    ob_start();           
    if (preg_match_all($pattern, $get_me_buffers, $get_me_buffers_return, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER)) {             
        echo $source = preg_replace_callback($pattern, function($matches){
             preg_match('/src="([^"]+)"/', $matches[0], $match);
             $src = $match[1];
             $contents = str_replace($src, '', $matches[0]);
            return $html ='<div class="test-iframe-block" style="background-color: lightgray;text-align: center;">'
                    . '<button style="margin: 5px;background-color: blue;color: white;" type="button" class="test-iframe-content-button-click" data-url=' . $src . ' data-type="iframe">Click to load content Third Party Control</button>'
                    . '<span style="display:none;">' . $contents . '</span>'
                    . '</div>';
         }, $get_me_buffers);
    } else {
        echo $get_me_buffers;
    }
    ob_flush();
}
```